# Is "slightly deform" a well defined concept in mathematical proof?

Tags: terminology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

In topological proofs the phrase "slightly deform" is widely used. To me, although I can accept the idea intuitively, the phrase "slightly deform" does not sound like a strict mathematical concept.

For example, a knot diagram is defined to be a projection of a knot onto some plane — a curve with finitely many self-intersection points called crossings. All crossings are required to be transversal double points and for each crossing there is an additional information of which part of the knot goes above and which one goes below.

But how does one prove that each knot has at least one knot diagram? I suppose that in the proof to such a statement, you probably will see the phrase "slightly deform" or a similar idea. For example, to get rid of triple crossings, one may need to "slightly deform" a part of a knot.

Even if it is intuitively understandable, how does one define "slightly deform" at all? Until it is unambiguously defined, I do not feel comfortable to use it in proofs.

**Edit:** The following paragraph was quoted from Braid Groups by C. Kassel and V. Turaev.[image]

I find myself very reluctant to accept the claim that "*Moreover, if $b$, $b'$ are generic polygonal braids related by a sequence of $\Delta$-moves, then slightly deforming the vertices of the intermediate polygonal braids, we can ensure that these polygonal braids
are also generic.*" How can one prove this statement?

Comment: I have only a very basic background in algebraic topology, but I can tell you my experience: the phrase "slightly deform" is a labor-saving device of tremendous efficiency and high safety. The proofs involved in a rigorous deformation argument tend to be extremely long and unwieldy, and do not really enhance anyone's understanding, except for those just entering the field. (counterexamples, of course, can be tremendously insightful.)

Comment: @EricStucky, I would completely agree with the efficiency. But without even a proper definition, how are we sure that it is 100% safe? In the braid example I quoted above, I am not sure how to ensure the safety of "slightly deforming".

Comment: It's not. But such is the nature of things. You should go through a few examples with totally watertight deformation arguments, and what I suspect you'll find (as I did) is that for low-dimensional examples there really is very little to worry about, and you will generally be able to tell when there is. I hope I don't sound unsympathetic; I find this aspect of the field frustrating, too. But unfortunately it seems there's not much to be done about it, in as much as this is the response I usually get from people who actually know something when I voice my concerns.

Comment: Slightly off topic but there isn't any concrete notion of a "slight" deform when one considers the deformation cohomology of a Lie Algebriod in the classical sense. The cohomology of the Lie Algebroid follows the usual cohain complex structure. However, when one considers the deformation quanitization of a Poisson structure associated to a Lie Algebroid, the canonical Lie Bracket is a Lie Algebroid; in some of my work  I was able to show that a "slight" deformity could occur in the Poisson bracket (as written down as higher order terms in some small $\epsilon$.

Comment: Zuriel: Are you familiar with generic transversality? If not, read, say, the book by Guillemin and Pollack on differential topology. Once you know what it is, you can easily justify "slightly deform" and will even start using it yourself!

Comment: @studiosus, I am not familiar with that topic; thank you for the comment; if I have time I would love to read more on differential topology.

Comment: Zuriel: I do not know the book you are reading, but I am pretty sure the authors assume familiarity with basic differential topology.

Comment: @studiosus, I am reading Braid Groups (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, vol. 247) by Christian Kassel and Vladimir Turaev. I did not know that basic differential topology is a prerequisite to Braid Theory.